# Scheduled Task as Administrators doesn't run at Log On for some users

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have deployed a Windows 10 Scheduled Task on about 250 PCs, to run at Log On as Administrators with Highest Privileges. I used a batch file to remotely install the Task on these PCs, and it runs on only half of them. I have five groups of users in three cities. Cities A and B with one group each (I think) work fine. City C with 3 groups of users, doesn't run (with a small handful of exceptions).

The Task shows error 0x41303 - "the task has not yet run", even if I run it manually or using a command line request. Task Scheduler History shows that it was initiated with these attempts, but with no error.

What could prevent the Task from doing anything or even giving an error in one city rather than another?

I am guessing it has something to do with the groups of users defined in Active Directory, but I know little about that and didn't see anything when I tried to examine it.

Comment: Some Groups were added to some Group Policy Objects representing the users, and for most users the task began running. Not sure about the few stragglers yet.

Comment: For about a dozen users of more than 200, it still won't run. Something about their PC or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing the City A and B groups to the City C groups in Active Directory, I saw that some permission groups were missing. I  didn't set these things up, and it was out of my hands, but higher up Admins made the changes and then it worked, except for about 18 PCs that still do not.

"*Use your Groups*"!